# How use function in Parse Library code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, parsing

I use a parser library in CodeIgniter for templates.
Assume i have the below html code

```
<html><body><p>Hello {name}</p></body></html>
```

and my Controller is:

```
$data['name'] = 'Jason';
$this->parser->parse('view',$data);
```

now I want to use the function in the html code below:

```
<html><body><p>Hello **strtolower({name})**</p></body></html>
```

Is it possible to use a function in the parse tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :

```
public function home_page() {
    $theme = "<html><body><p>Hello".strtolower("'{name}'")."</p></body></html>";
    $frame = $this->parser->parse($theme, array('name'=>'DENY'), TRUE);
    $this->parser->parse("index-page.html", $frame);
}
```

Comment: No,i want to use example {date("F j, Y, g:i a")} or {strtolower(name)}

Comment: sorry omid, you can manipulation code in your function , example : $data['name'] = strtolower('Jason'); and view just display your manipulation result.

Comment: glad to help you, if you have problem with codeigniter you can contact me.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done out of the box, that I know of. You'll have to extend the Parser Library. I did a quick Google search and found this. It seems to be what you're looking for, although it is 4 years old..

https://gist.github.com/svizion/3480575

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend.
I did see but i cannot use it.Is there example?

Comment: Once you've loaded the library, you can use PHP functions like this; {date("F j, Y, g:i a")}

Comment: Again, this is a few years old so it may not work with your version of Codeigniter, but it should give you an idea how to achieve it.